# rails number_to_currency bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have a rails app (rails version 2.1.0) and today I found a very weird error.

A money value(mysql decimal column with precision 8 and scale 2) is 86.02. However, number_to_currency method returns "$86.20". This happens only in production server. My dev server returns correctly. The production server is red hat and dev is ubuntu.

This is also confirmed in console.

```ruby
>> p.deposit_total.to_s 
=> "86.02"
>> helper.number_to_currency p.deposit_total 
=> "$86.20"
```

Is this a known issue?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: I narrowed down the problem.

b=BigDecimal("86.02")

b.to_f => 86.2

This only happens in the production server. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think this might be ruby bug. This happens in irb. ruby version is 1.8.5.

Comment: This might be only BigDecimal bug. irb(main):023:0> BigDecimal.new("1.0234")
=> #<BigDecimal:b7efb05c,'0.1234E1',8(12)>

The internal representation is wrong.

Comment: fwiw, the first comment example doesn't occur in ruby 1.8.7 or 1.8.6 (at least the REE version)

Comment: I confirmed that this error is not related to ruby version. Then it's probably hardware or system configuration problem. How can I find it?

Comment: Using ruby-debug might be useful in this case to step through the code.

Comment: A real fix for this might even require some digging into the Ruby core code. I assume `b = BigDecimal("86.02") b.to_s # => "86.2"` as well?

Answer (score 0):

For us this problem was caused by the wrong minor version of ruby.  See: https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2010-0012.html

Server with the problem:

```
[auser@aserver01 ~]$ rpm -qa | grep ruby
ruby-libs-1.8.5-5.7
ruby-rdoc-1.8.5-5.7
ruby-1.8.5-5.7
ruby-devel-1.8.5-5.7
ruby-irb-1.8.5-5.7
```

Server without the problem:

```
[auser@aserver02 ~]$ rpm -qa | grep ruby
ruby-1.8.5-5.5
ruby-ri-1.8.5-5.5
ruby-irb-1.8.5-5.5
ruby-rdoc-1.8.5-5.5
ruby-libs-1.8.5-5.5
ruby-devel-1.8.5-5.5
```